# fetch [cdata] content with php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am reading this tutorial on fetching RSS feeds using PHP Simple XML.
Reason I wanna do it myself instead of Wordpress plugin is because of lack of displaying images.
Using this tutorial I thought I was going to be able to go through nodes myself and display what I want but I am not even fetching data I need because it is enclosed within `![CDATA]`:

```
 <description>
<![CDATA[
<img src="http://images.highspeedbackbone.net/SKUimages/small/m17-1023-main666-tmc.jpg"/><br/> The Microsoft Office Home and Business 2010 Product Key Card brings together the roles of managing a business, running a household and helping with ho
]]>
</description>
```

So I am after that `img` tag, but it's not there using this code from tutorial:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://rss.linksynergy.com/promo.rss?promoid=3076&token=8c86517642801a8d4e1132xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx35e66a3');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
```

Any suggestions welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: And what's your next step with $xml? How are you displaying the description value?

Comment: My primary concern is to get that img src so I can use photo next to text description, but it is not there when I `print_r($xml)`

Comment: $xml is a simpleXMLElement instance, not a block of text, use simpleXMLElement mechanisms (as described in the manual) to display the description data from that element

Comment: My concern is that data I need is not fetched. Like I said, while printing out variable `img` tag is not there. Anyways will take a look at manual. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

This will parse CDATA-Elements into normal text nodes so you can access them like any other text with `$xml['decription']`

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php for reference.

Comment: Oh sorry my fault... i looked up the parameters from the wrong function, the object class name is not specified if not using `simplexml_load_string` - I updated the answer

Comment: Why is PHP documented in such a weird way?? Couldn't they just write in somewhere appropriate?? :)

Comment: PHP is not documented in a weird way... PHP is **IMPLEMENTED** in a weird way... I'm at the moment learning for the Zend Certification (this is actually one of the reasons to be here answering questions as this is the nicest way to learn some of that strange stuff PHP includes) and there is a huge mess of inconsistent function naming and parameter orders... it's just no fun...